# How to perform algebra when working with parallel vectors.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find $t$ if the given vectors are parallel:

$$OR = (t , t + 2)$$

$$OS = (3 , -4)$$

I easily understand the question if the vectors are perpendicular, because the dot product of perpendicular vectors is $0$, which means you can equate the vectors to $0$ and work it out that way, but I don't understand how to answer this question with parallel vectors! And it's very frustrating!

Is there a similar rule with parallel vectors that I am unaware of?

Also, my apologies for the rubbish formatting. I haven't got the hang of mathjax yet.

Comment: Math formatting has been taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two vectors are parallel if they have the same slope. The slope of $(x,y)$ is $\frac{y}{x}$; so it suffices to equate
$$\frac{t+2}{t} = \frac{-4}{3}$$
and find $t=-\frac{6}{7}$.

Comment: Thank-you so much. That makes a lot of sense. Would a similar method work with vectors in three or four dimensions? I've never worked out the gradient of a three-dimensional linear graph.

Comment: @ben8615 no this doesn't generalize. Another way to solve this is to note that if $v$ and $u$ are parallel that means there exists some scalar $\lambda$ such that $v = \lambda u$.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of two parallel vectors is equal to the product of their magnitudes. Thus you have $3t -4(t+2) = 5\sqrt{t^2 + (t+2)^2}$. The second solution comes from the fact that the dot product of two antiparallel vectors is also equal to the product of their  magnitudes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, because that doesn't have solutions, apparently.

Comment: $v\cdot w = \|v\|\|w\|\cos \theta$

Comment: perhaps some calculation error...

Comment: No, it needs to be the negative square root. [See graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r1oogtsx0d)

Comment: that's fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are parallel if and only if they are scalar multiples of each other. In this case that means there exists some $k$ such that $k(3,-4)=(t,t+2)$. Now comparing coordinates we see that $3k=t$ and $-4k=t+2$ which is a system of two equations and two unknowns. Solving this system gives us $k=-\frac27$ and  $t=-\frac67$.